# How to make the bass synth in Regal - Fenix (Amelie Lens Remix)?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer

I would like to reproduce the bass synth that we can hear in [Regal - Fenix (Amelie Lens Remix)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shGpsg1RKjY&t=86s). From the link, we can hear it alone until 1:30.

What strategy can be used to produce this sound?
I mention that I'm not talking about the side chain effect but the synth sound in itself.

Answer (score 1):

That is what is referred to as a “Reese bass” sound.  You can find many, many tutorials on YouTube on how to make it, many of them focused around Serum, but once you see some examples, you can translate the techniques to whatever you have available (which you don’t mention).  Also, that’s not side-chaining, it’s modulation within the sound itself.

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary that I didn't know. Actually I'm am wondering if it's the synth that we can hear at [2:34](https://youtu.be/shGpsg1RKjY?t=154) that would be low-pass filtered. If so, is it still considered as a Reese bass? Do you know how to reproduce it specifically, for example with Serum?

Comment: Yes, you can hear the sound being filtered by a low-pass filter with the cutoff being lowered and raised throughout the track.  No, this does not change what it's called. 
 Generally speaking (not specific to Serum) you want two sawtooth waves tuned an octave apart with some detuning.  The modulation is an LFO routed to some combination of filter and amp to taste.  Do you have Serum?  I'd be surprised if there wasn't a preset that gives you something similar.